# How do you find first character NOT in string array without using classes or libraries when comparing two strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I am trying to compare two string arrays, but am not allowed to use classes or libraries to assist.

The issue I have with this is that if one string is more than one character, then it compares the whole string to again, even though it already checked the first one.

```
char *find_first_not_in_the_set(char *str, const char *set)
{
    for(int i = 0; *(str + i) != '\0'; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; *(set + j) != '\0'; j++)
        {
            if(str[i] != set[j])  
            {
                return &(str[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

If "Hello World!" is the first string and the second string is "He". The program should return `l`, but it returns `H` because it still checks the first character.

Comment: It's because you are comparing the first character of `str` with whole `set` string. Make it in one loop.

Comment: IMHO, your attempt is not that bad. Did you try to debug it? Your inner loop has a flaw. Please, note that if you compare the first character `H` of `str` with the characters `H` and `e` in `set`, only one of the latter can be equal to the former. The other will cause an (too) early bail out. Try to fix the inner loop that you bail out only if all of `set` doesn't match the current character of `str`.

Comment: @Ternvein _Make it in one loop._ How should this work? Please, note the constraint _not allowed to use classes or libraries to assist_.

Comment: @Scheff, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use this:

```
bool matrix[256] = {0};
int length = strlen(set);
// remember all characters we have in the 'set'
for( int i=0; i<length; i++) matrix[set[i] & 0xFF] = 1;

length = strlen(str);
// now check the characters from 'str'
for( int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    if( ! matrix[str[i] & 0xFF] ) {
        printf( "Found: %c", str[i] );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not bad - one loop. I'm impressed. ;-) (Strictly speaking, these are still two loops but they are not nested anymore. -> O(M+N) instead of O(M*N).)

Answer (score 0):

For every character in str, your code checks if it is present on each and every position in set.Thus, when i=0 'H' is compared with set[0] i.e. 'H' for j=0.But when j=1,'H' is compared with 'e' and this causes the function to return str[0] because i is still 0.

Your problem will be solved if you use just one loop and check str[i]!=set[i].

Comment: _Your problem will be solved if you use just one loop and check str[i]!=set[i]._ I'm afraid this is simply wrong.

Comment: As I understood OPs question, the assignment requests to (roughly) resemble [std::strspn()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strspn). What you suggest sounds like `strcmp()`.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a break statement and boolean to complete this